# How reactive programming back-pressure is different from traditional pagination?

Tags: java, scala, pagination, rx-java, reactive-programming

I've just started studying  [reactive-programming](https://www.reactivemanifesto.org/glossary) and I am confused with the term [Back-Pressure](https://www.reactivemanifesto.org/glossary#Back-Pressure).

According to docs :

> This back-pressure is an important feedback mechanism that allows
>   systems to gracefully respond to load rather than collapse under it.

What I understand from it, is: Client will ask the number of records he wants at a particular time and the back-end will respond only to the asked records.

But isn't is same as Pagination? We can also query backend the records we are interested in using Pagination.

How these two are different?

Could someone please explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pagination is as you said, a client asks for a number of records and gets that number of records in return.

Back-pressure is used to monitor the system to make sure that the system's load is acceptable.

For example:

> Let's say you have an application that is supposed to pick up and process files. The users upload files to a directory, and your application has two components, one that picks up the files from the directory (component A) and one that processes those files (component B).
>
> Pretend that the processing component (B) can only handle 100 files at a time, otherwise it will crash due to memory issues, or any other resource problem that may happen.
>
> A form of back-pressure is for the component that picks up files from the directory (A) to also monitor how many files are currently being processed by component B. If component A sees that component B is overloaded or is close to being overloaded, component A can stop sending files to component B. This will prevent component B from crashing.
>
> Component A will continue to monitor the load and send files when component B is available.

What is the benefit of this?

There may be a time of day, week, month or year that your system receives more than usual number of requests or data. You don't want it to crash at that time, and you also don't want to add more resources that are only used every now and then. You can use back-pressure to pace the incoming data.

Back-pressure can also prevent loss of data. In the example above, after users upload the files and the files are read and sent to processing they may deleted to free up space. If the system crashes during processing, you have to hunt down which files were processed and which were being processed but failed and restore them or get a new copy from the users.